# Add class to a views field depending on image's being vertical or horizontal

Tags: views, theming, media

I have a view that outputs an image field. I would like to add a class to the `.views-field` div (for example, actually a `views-row` would also do the job) depending on whether the image is vertical (length > height) or horizontal (height > width).

I tried making a custom `views-view-field-tpl.php` for outputting the view's field, but I have no idea how to access the image or the image data.

EDIT: I've found that `$field` contains `additional_fields`, which in turns includes `field_photo_width` and `field_photo_height`. Those are arrays, though, and I have no idea how to get an actual value from them.

Comment: Arrays keys can be accessed with square brackets `$array['value']`. And object properties/methods can be accessed with an arrow `$object->property`. You can also have arrays inside objects: `$node->field_body['value']`.

Comment: You might be better off using preprocessors in your theme's template.php file. This way you can do the calculation in a function, which is way neater.

Comment: @Beebee : my problem is not about accessing arrays. Iexpected those to be simple numericals, representing the number of pixels, not an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer could be approached from various angles. Simpler perhaps would be to target the template_preprocess_image itself, and add a div wrapper around it with the class, or just add the class on the img tag. I chose to do it via template_preprocess_field.

```
function THEME_preprocess_field(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['element']['#field_name'] == 'field_IMAGE_NAME') {
    foreach($vars['items'] as $key => $item){
      if (_add_image_proportions_class($item)) {
        if ($item['#item']['width'] > $item['#item']['height']) {
          $vars['classes_array'][] = 'landscape';
        }
        else if ($item['#item']['width'] < $item['#item']['height']) {
          $vars['classes_array'][] = 'portrait';
        }
        else {
          $vars['classes_array'][] = 'square';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function _add_image_proportions_class($item) {
  return $item['#image_style'] == 'medium';
}
```

_add_image_proportions_class() is just a function you implement to test whether you want to add the class or not. In my example, I targeted the image style that is applied to the image. You could for instance create a specific image style that is used only for that view, and target it specifically. Or you could test the path you are on, etc.

Comment: Could you tell me if it is possible to add those classes also to the wrapper?